# SQL query returns inflated count when using inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to count the number of times Encrypted or Denied appears in a certain column. The code below returns that with out a problem

```
use DEW
SELECT Count (distinct DeviceData.machinename) As [Number Of Devices], 
DeviceData.CurrentSite, DeviceData.Country
  ,sum(case buildstatus when 'encrypted' then 1 else 0 end) encrypted
  ,sum(case buildstatus when 'Denied' then 1 else 0 end) Denied
FROM dbo.DeviceData
where currentsite = 'REN'
group by DeviceData.Country, CurrentSite
```

Ouput is like this:

```
Number of Devices SiteCode Country Encrypted Denied
       3             REN    Greece    0         3
```

However when I add an inner join

```
FROM dbo.DeviceData JOIN dbo.SiteList ON dbo.DeviceData.country = dbo.SiteList.Country
```

the number of denied changes to 33.

Any idea why SQL is doing this?

Comment: Are you also putting more columns in the select and in the group by part?

Comment: For one DeviceData, does it have one SiteList only? `FROM dbo.DeviceData JOIN dbo.SiteList ON dbo.DeviceData.country = dbo.SiteList.Country`

Comment: I do need to add more columns but even if I don't the denied result still gets changed to 33

Comment: Try joining on the `Site`, not the `Country`, as per my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine that there are 11 sites for Greece in the `SiteList` table. Therefore, the result is as expected.

If you did the following:

```
SELECT 
    DeviceData.machinename,
    SiteList.Country,
    SiteList.Site, -- Or whatever the column is called...
FROM dbo.DeviceData JOIN 
     dbo.SiteList ON 
         dbo.DeviceData.country = dbo.SiteList.Country
```

You will see 33 rows being returned:

```
MACHINENAME    COUNTRY    SITE
Machine#1      Greece     Site1
Machine#1      Greece     Site2
Machine#1      Greece     Site3
Machine#1      Greece     Site4
Machine#1      Greece     Site5
Machine#1      Greece     Site6
Machine#1      Greece     Site7
Machine#1      Greece     Site8
Machine#1      Greece     Site9
Machine#1      Greece     Site10
Machine#1      Greece     Site11
Machine#2      Greece     Site1
Machine#2      Greece     Site2
Machine#2      Greece     Site3
Machine#2      Greece     Site4
etc...
```

I think the fix you need is to join on the `Site`, not the `Country`.

```
 FROM dbo.DeviceData JOIN 
      dbo.SiteList ON 
           dbo.DeviceData.CurrentSite = dbo.SiteList.Site
```

Comment: there are 11 sites in the sitelist table for greece. But if I'm trying to count the number of times denied appears in the devicedata table why is the output being multipled by 11?